# DBT MySQL producing boolean columns as INT, should be TINYINT

Tags: mysql, boolean, dbt, tinyint

I'm trying to change how we make some transformations in our tables on RDS MySql. This table have 20 million records and 200 columns. We have a pipeline executed monthly where we download the table to an EC2, use python to do the transformation, then it is reuploaded.

Upon presenting dbt, boss wants to see it working because of the benefits: everything will stay on SQL (I am the only python person in our small 20 people company), will have documentation, automated tests and version control [all this is really needed at the moment]. I made it happen, wrote SQL on dbt that produces the same results of the python script and runs directly on the mysql database using this https://pypi.org/project/dbt-mysql/ adapter.

There are some problems and the one of them i think will start helping me most is about the boolean in mysql. I already know all that thing about boolean, tinyint(1), etc, etc. But all columns intended to be "boolean" are going to the tables as INT, and I want them as tinyint, because it is taking 4 times the space it should.

Edit: added more information thanks to feedback

My raw table comes with all columns as str, i'm trying to cast the correct types. As this one should be boolean, i expected it to be converted to tinyint(1). When I create a table via pandas and there is a bool column, the table column is tinyint(1). But when I try to do something like this in SQL, the column becomes int.

The code is really just that:

```sql
SELECT IF(myStrColumn = '1', TRUE, FALSE)
FROM myRawTable
```

The resulting column is given as int, but i wanted it to be tinyint(1) to represent boolean.

tinyint is not a valid type to be passed to cast as per documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast so it doesn't work

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider adding code and a reproducible example to your question. We don't know what exactly you've tried and what's not working. For example, did you try casting the boolean fields to tinyint?

Comment: Without any code examples to show how `int` may be getting set, we have no way to know?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i updated the question with more information.
@tconbeer as i added in the edit, casting as tinyint is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the MySQL docs, I think you have two options:

1. Create a new, custom table materialization that allows you to leverage the MySQL syntax:

```sql
create table my_table (my_col tinyint) as select ...
```

2. Add a post-hook that narrows the column after you've created the table:

```sql
config(
    materialized="table",
    post_hook="alter table {{ this }} modify my_col tinyint"
)
```

For #1, there is a guide to [creating materializations](https://docs.getdbt.com/guides/legacy/creating-new-materializations) in the dbt docs, but it is a complex and advanced topic. I think the `dbt-mysql` adapter uses the vanilla/default table materialization in the [global project](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/blob/main/core/dbt/include/global_project/macros/materializations/models/table/table.sql). You may want to check out the MySQL incremental materialization macro, which is [here](https://github.com/dbeatty10/dbt-mysql/blob/main/dbt/include/mysql/macros/materializations/incremental/incremental.sql).

Comment: Oh wow! It really worked! I went for the second option because you said the first one was advanced, so I tried it and it worked straight up. Thank you very much!